# fs.writeFile and writeFileSync save empty files in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, fs

I am attempting in Node/Express to convert an html text field generated using Quill's rich text editor to a docx file.

both fs.writeFile and writeFileSync are saving an empty file. Here is the updated route in line with the comments below:

```
// convert html to docx file
router.post('/:id/html_to_docx', auth.required, async (req, res, next) => {
  let id = req.params.id
  let piece = await Piece.query().findById( id )
  var docx = HtmlDocx.asBlob(piece.body);
  console.log('this is docx: ', docx )

  const outputFile = `${__dirname}/temp/html2docxconversion.docx`

  fs.writeFileSync(outputFile, docx, { encoding: null })
  res.json({
    success: true, message: 'ok' 
  });
})
```

Comment: Did you check that the docx variable is not empty?

Comment: yes. output of console.log is "<Buffer 50 4b 03 04 0a 00 00 00 00 00 02 6b 8d..."

Comment: You are mixing fs.writeFile and fs.writeFileSync, it's either `fs.writeFile(file, data[, options], callback)` or `fs.writeFileSync(file, data[, options])`

Answer (score 0):

`fs.writeFileSync` and `fs.writeFile` use `'utf8'` encoding by default.
You should pass the option `{ enconding: null }` to explicitly write the data as binary.

```
  fs.writeFileSync(outputFile, docx, { encoding: null })
```

Comment: Tried this but still getting a blank file.  Route updated above to reflect your suggestion.  File size is listed as 6kb, but I see no text.

Comment: I suspect that the input of HtmlDocx.asBlob might be incorrect, cant you try a simple `HtmlDocx.asBlob('<!doctype html><html><body>Test content</body></html>')` or something similar?

Comment: Did that now. still blank.

Comment: If I put a pure string in , I get a text file back. if I hard code html like "<p> this is a paragraph</p>" I get cannot open this file.

Comment: There might be a problem with your html input,  are you sure the html is valid? Have you tried the node.js example https://github.com/evidenceprime/html-docx-js-node-sample ?

Comment: Actually even on the demo site here: http://evidenceprime.github.io/html-docx-js/test/sample.html. I click "convert" and a blank docx file is returned. Maybe it's the library?

Comment: There might be some issues with the application you are using to open the docx. I'm on Word for macOS and I can open the test document just fine